# Upadating documents not possible due to lack of atomic operators?

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to update my collection through mongodb shell but unsuscessfully due to this error:
"Update document requires atomic operators"

```
db.dogs_main_breed.updateMany([
  {},
  {
    $unwind: "$Behavior"
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $mergeObjects: [
          "$$ROOT",
          "$Behavior"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      Behavior: 0
    }
  }
])
```

How could be possible to update my documents given this query?

My goal is to flatten "Behavior" field and include it in Root directory of my document:

```
"breed": "Akita",
  "origin": "Japan",
  "url": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akita_(dog)",
  "img": "some img url",
  "WikiDescr": [
    {
      "contenido": "Content"
    }
  ],
  "Behavior": [
    {
      "good_with_children": 3,
      "good_with_other_dogs": 1,
    }
```

Desired output:

```
"breed": "Akita",
  "origin": "Japan",
  "url": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akita_(dog)",
  "img": "some img url",
  "good_with_children": 3,
  "good_with_other_dogs": 1,
  "WikiDescr": [
    {
      "contenido": "Content"
    }
  ],
```

Comment: Hey @Alberto Martinez Lasheras can you provide some more details like what is it initial state of document and what should be the updated state of document after update query

Comment: Ok , I added some more details to my question. Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try out this query?

```
db.dogs_main_breed.aggregate([
  {
    '$unwind': '$Behavior'
  }, {
    '$replaceRoot': {
      'newRoot': {
        '$mergeObjects': [
          '$$ROOT', '$Behavior'
        ]
      }
    }
  }, {
    '$project': {
      'Behavior': 0
    }
  }, {
    '$out': 'dogs_main_breed'
  }
])
```

Here the link of [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zCtouHqDMe_) to try out the query